# Create Gradient On Color Seekbar

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, kotlin, qr-code

I am working on Android app that have to change Image Color to Gradient at Runtime. I have Implemented to change two different color on a Single Image at Runtime But the issue I am Facing is It change Only a Static Value Like Fixed Color I have added Like

```
 for (x in 0 until width) {
            for (y in 0 until height) {
                if (bitMatrix.get(x, y)) {
                    val red = (56 - (56.0 - 14.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val green = (247 - (247.0 - 145.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val blue = (195 - (195.0 - 79.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val colorInt = argb(255, red, green, blue)
                    // Modify the color of the QR code, you can separately develop the color of the QR code and background
                    pixels[x * height + y] = if (bitMatrix.get(x, y)) colorInt else 16777215// 0x000000:0xffffff
                } else {
                    pixels[x * height + y] = 0x00ffffff// background color
                }
            }
```

What I want is It Change the Color through RGB Gradient over Seekbar I have Added
This is how I am Changing two colors of image of a Single Image:

The Code to Use 1 Function to Create Gradient, It is Creating Gradient But Statically but as I try to Use Gradient Functionality on Seek-bar it doesn't work and Gradient is only be able to change with single color

The Code Right Now

```
    fun createQRGradientImage(url: String?, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap? {
    try {
        if (url == null || "" == url || url.length < 1) {
            return null
        }
        val hints: Hashtable<Any?, Any?> = Hashtable<Any?, Any?>()
        hints[EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET] = "utf-8"
        hints[EncodeHintType.MARGIN] = 0
        // Image data conversion, using matrix conversion
        val bitMatrix = QRCodeWriter().encode(url, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height)
        val width = bitMatrix.width
        val height = bitMatrix.height
        val pixels = IntArray(width * height)

        // Gradient color draw from top to bottom
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {

                if (bitMatrix[x, y]) { // QR code color

                    
                    val red = (56 - (56.0 - 14.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val green = (247 - (247.0 - 145.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val blue = (195 - (195.0 - 79.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val color = Color()
                    val colorInt = Color.argb(255, red, green, blue)

                    // Modify the color of the QR code, you can separately develop the color of the QR code and background
                    pixels[y * width + x] =
                        if (bitMatrix[x, y]) colorInt else 16777215 // 0x000000:0xffffff
                } else {
                    pixels[y * width + x] = 0x00ffffff // background color
                }
            }
        }

        // Generate the format of the QR code image, using ARGB_8888
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)

        return bitmap
   //     img_bitmap1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    } catch (e: WriterException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

But this Code Give This on Debug Level
[image: Debug Level]

The Above things is Image Achieved by this Code

```
 if (bitMatrix[x, y]) { // QR code color


                    val red = (56 - (56.0 - 14.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val green = (247 - (247.0 - 145.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val blue = (195 - (195.0 - 79.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt()
                    val color = Color()
                    val colorInt = Color.argb(255, red, green, blue)

                    // Modify the color of the QR code, you can separately develop the color of the QR code and background
                    pixels[y * width + x] =
                        if (bitMatrix[x, y]) colorInt else 16777215 // 0x000000:0xffffff
                } else {
                    pixels[y * width + x] = 0x00ffffff // background color
                }
```

What i want is The Above code Should Work on Seek-bar Class Colors I have Created
Like in Seekbar I have Method

```
    fun pickColor(position: Float, canvasWidth: Int): Int {
    val value = (position - paddingStart) / (canvasWidth - (paddingStart + paddingEnd))
    when {
        value <= 0.0 -> return colorSeeds[0]
        value >= 1 -> return colorSeeds[colorSeeds.size - 1]
        else -> {
            var colorPosition = value * (colorSeeds.size - 1)
            val i = colorPosition.toInt()
            colorPosition -= i
            val c0 = colorSeeds[i]
            val c1 = colorSeeds[i + 1]

            val red = mix((56 - (56.0 - 14.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt(),Color.red(c1), colorPosition)
            val green = mix((247 - (247.0 - 145.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt(), Color.green(c1), colorPosition)
            val blue = mix((195 - (195.0 - 79.0) / height * (y + 1)).toInt(), Color.blue(c1), colorPosition)
          //  return Color.rgb( red, green, blue)
            return Color.argb(255, red, green, blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have two functions instead of one(?). In any case, neither of them seem to do anything in their respective loops that would change the color they plot. Why don't you just write a single function that generates the entire image, and linearly interpolates between the first and second color as it goes along?